# Object Oriented Programming (Python) Code

Tags: python, oop

This is a practice code. I understand everything except how to make the weights compare. I want the other weight to be 40 and print "Spot Wins!"

```
class Pet:

 def __init__(self,myname,mykind,myweight,mycost):
   self.name = myname
   self.kind = mykind
   self.weight = myweight
   self.cost = mycost
   self.speak()
   self.isexpensive()
   # self.battle(40) This is where the error happens

 def speak(self):
   if self.kind == 'dog':
       print('Woof!')
   elif self.kind == 'cat':
       print('Meow!')
   else:
       print('I am mute')             

 def battle(self,other):
   if self.weight > other.weight:
       print(self.name + ' wins!')
   else:
       print(other.name + ' wins!')

 def grow(self):
   self.weight = self.weight + 5

 def isexpensive(self):
   if self.cost > 500:
       return True
   else:
       return False

spot = Pet('Spot','dog',50,550)
```

Comment: You don't put `self.battle(40)` in the constructor. You call `spot.battle(Pet(...))` later on the **instance** of the Pet class.

Answer (score 1):

`battle()` requires something with a `.weight` attribute (like a `Pet`), but you're passing in a number (`integer`). You shouldn't put it inside the `__init__` function since one of the ways would be to create another `Pet`, which tries to make another `Pet` to `battle` ad infinium.

However, if you add another `Pet`, `Lassie` after `spot` and tell `spot.battle(Lassie)`, it'll compare them with your function.

Comment: thanks i get it now